# 日本語のソフトウェアに関する質問が英語で寄せられた場合

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

以前、Karabinerというソフトに関する質問が英語で寄せられたことがありました。

[Karabinerの設定ファイルがうまく動かない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/9310)

何故わざわざここで質問するのだろうと思っていたのですが、日本語のソフトウェアだから、日本語を使う人の多い場所に来たのではないかと思い至りました。

また [Monaca / OnsenUI](http://www.asial.co.jp/pressrelease/427) や [Olympus Camera Kit](https://opc.olympus-imaging.com/sdkdocs/data/inquiry/inquiry.html) など、スタック・オーバーフローをユーザーフォーラムとして紹介するケースが出てきていますが、こちらについても英語での質問がありました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/9869

さて、このような質問についても常に日本語で質問してもらうようお願いし、難しいようであれば英語版サイトへ移行すべきでしょうか？あるいは英語のまま（もしくは誰かが訳を追加して）ここで受け入れてもよいと思いますか？

Comment: 英語版サイトには適切なタグが見つからなかったと言う事情も考えられます。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

自分は英語が苦手なので偉そうなことは言えないのですが、日本語版だから無条件に日本語以外は受け付けないというのはちょっと閉鎖的なのではないかなと思います。

> 日本語のソフトウェアだから、日本語を使う人の多い場所に来た

自分は全然思い至りませんでしたが、これならば自然な流れだと思いますし、
ひとまず日本語で書いてくれると嬉しいなという呼びかけ（コメント）はするけど、
それが難しい場合でも可能な限りは受け入れるというスタンスで良いのかなという気がします。

・英語だと尻込みして結局放置されてしまうのではないか
・日本語訳を追加するとなると、一部の方に負荷が集中してしまうのではないか

といった点は考える必要がありそうですが・・・。